# Firebase inAppMessaging events not getting captured

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-in-app-messaging

i am sending inApp messages from firebase console. messages are getting delivered but i am not able to capture the events from it i.e. dismiss event, impression event, clicked event from it. all the resources are on latest versions(Xcode, cocoa pods, firebase). can someone help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    InAppMessaging.inAppMessaging().delegate = self
```

Extend the appDelegate to InAppMessagingDisplayDelegate

Comment: i am asking about in-app events, not on the dashboard.

Comment: @hussain have you self the delegate ??

Comment: i was making it wrong, the right way is extend delegates to app delegate only, not to any NSObject